# Why am I getting TypeError: obj.addEventListener is not a function?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Here's my code:

```
function addEvent( obj, type, fn ) {
  if ( obj.attachEvent ) {
    obj['e'+type+fn] = fn;
    obj[type+fn] = function(){obj['e'+type+fn]( window.event );}
    obj.attachEvent( 'on'+type, obj[type+fn] );
  } else
    obj.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
}

function alertWinner(){
    alert("You may be a winner!");
}

function showWinner (){
    var aTag = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    addEvent(aTag, 'click', alertWinner);
}

showWinner();
```

Basically, I'm working in the firebug console and trying to get an alert to pop up when any a tag is clicked.

I can't see the problem that results in this not working and giving me the error stated in my questions title (viewed in firebug).  Anybody?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`document.getElementsByTagName` returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList) of DOM elements. Each element has an `addEventListener` function, but the array doesn't have one.

Loop over it:

```
function showWinner (){
    var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i=0;i<aTags.length;i++){
        addEvent(aTags[i], 'click', alertWinner);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not an array, it is a NodeList.

Comment: this seems like it should work and yet I'm now getting: referrenceError: aTags is not defined.

Comment: @max7 Did you rename the variable to `aTags` with the "s" at the end?

Answer (score 7):

`aTag` is an instance of `DOMNodeList`, not from `DOMElement`.

You could do this instead:

```
var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var aTag = aTags[0];
```

But obviously this approach presents a flaw, in that there might be more than one `a` element returned. You should use a different selector that returns only one element, if possible.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure why, but I got `addEvent is not defined` in Firefox. I couldn't even find `addEvent()` on MDN. I had to use this:

```
function showWinner (){
    var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i=0;i<aTags.length;i++){
        // addEvent(aTags[i], 'click', alertWinner);
        aTags[i].addEventListener("click", alertWinner);
    }
}
```

Comment: that's because addevent does not exist :)