# how to add and remove classes from HTML elements using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, toggle

My task is to modify the test.js code so that it will toggle the styles. This means that when a user clicks on the button a second time, it should revert back to its original state before it was changed.

This will require you to use conditional statements in JavaScript, which are very similar to the ones you used in Java.

How to add and remove classes from HTML elements using JavaScript ?

I was able to make the click work on my button so far here is my code

I have tried

```
var element = document.getElementById("h1");

if (element.classList) { 
   element.classList.toggle("title-button");
} else {

   var classes = element.className.split(" ");
   var i = classes.indexOf("title-button");

   if (i >= 0) 
     classes.splice(i, 1);
   else 
     classes.push("title-button");
     element.className = classes.join(" "); 
}
```

But it did not work

Here is what is working with only one click:

```
var buttonElement  = document.getElementById("title-button");

var elementsArray = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
var element = elementsArray[0];
buttonElement.addEventListener("click", function(){
    element.classList.add("bordered-text");
    element.style.color = "yellow";

});
```

Clicking the Alter Title button should enable the user to add or remove the styles that I have been working with. "title button" should become "Alter button" so when the user clicks on the title the style should change.

Comment: `if (element.classList)` this block will always execute.

Answer (score 0):

When you use getElementsByTagName() [you are getting a NodeList back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485030/why-am-i-getting-typeerror-obj-addeventlistener-is-not-a-function) so you have to loop over it to add the event listener properly:

```
let titles = document.getElementsByTagName("h1"); 

for (i=0; i<titles.length; i++){

  titles[i].addEventListener("click", function(){

    if(this.className === "title-button"){
      this.className = "alter-title";
    }else{
      this.className="title-button";
    }

  })

}
```

Here's a [CodePen where you can see the toggle in action](https://codepen.io/gemiller/pen/wObwGO).

[Here's where](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) you can learn more about "this" in Javascript.
[And here's where](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) you can learn more about NodeLists.

I would however recommend that you consider the longterm implications of targeting the h1 tag. Just be sure that you won't ever have h1 tags on the page that you don't want to have affected by the toggle because you are adding the event listener to all of the h1 tags. If there might be a case where you don't want h1 tags affected, consider using a special class for these elements and adding the event listeners to them by selecting them that way.